# Cannot detect json_encode result from mysql in ajax success

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to get the JSON response in success AJAX from MySql.
This is the Error i am getting in my console -> **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**

My AJAX Code.

```
    function getMessage(siteid)
    {   
    document.getElementById("add").disabled = true;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",               
        url: "checkSite.php",   
        data: { siteid : siteid }, //6 digit number
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            if(objData.status == "not available"){
                alert("Not Available");
                document.getElementById("add").disabled = false;
            }
            if(objData.status == "available"){
                alert("Available");
                document.getElementById("add").disabled = false;
            }
        },
        error: function(result){
            alert("error");
        }
    }); 
}
```

My checkSite.php

```
$siteid = $_POST['siteid']; 
if($siteid !=''){
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM  tablename WHERE siteid='$siteid'";
   $result2 = mysql_query($sql);
   if(mysql_num_rows($result2) > 0){        
       echo json_encode(array('status' => 'not available'));
   }
   else{            
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'available'));
   }        

}
```

Its showing me `parse Error. jQuery.parseJSON(data)` is not at all working.

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error on this line

```
data: { siteid : siteid }
```

add a comma at the end

```
data: { siteid : siteid },
                         ^
```

Comment: Thanks. but i have missed it here.. But my error is in success.

Comment: No Anish.. i have issues in Success AJAX.

Comment: This is my colsole.log(data)

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

{"status":"available"}
`

Comment: you are not returning a valid json, it has a doctype also with the json, so invalid json. so what you can do just either remove the doctype or **move your php code to a php file not on a php webpage**. I prefer the latter.

Comment: Jai, Please suggest me how to do the same. Thanks

Comment: @minspacesix yes.json format is not correct .  From where you are adding <!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> </head>  ? . Remove that one and it will work.  Also you can directly use data.status to get the status

Comment: make a blank php file and move your php code to that file and echo json from there Remember: do not put any html tag or comment in the json, that makes it invalid json.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this and `console.log` and check the result

```
$.ajax({            

    url         :   'checkSite.php',
    dataType    :   'json',
    cache       :   false,
    contentType :   false,
    processData :   false,
    data        :   { siteid : siteid },                           
    type        :   'post',
    success     :   function(data){ 
                    console.log (data);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",               
                url: "checkSite.php",   
                data: { siteid : siteid }, //6 digit number
                dataType : 'json'
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data.status == "not available"){
                        alert("Not Available");
                        document.getElementById("add").disabled = false;
                    }
                    if(data.status == "available"){
                        alert("Available");
                        document.getElementById("add").disabled = false;
                    }
                },
                error: function(result){
                    alert("error");
                }
            }); 
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not have else block for "if($siteid !='')" case, so you will get empty from this service call which can't be parse by JSON in success callback. for your case of exception this if condition"if($siteid !='')"  seemed to be failing.

So, you checksite.php should be like this shown below.

```
$siteid = $_POST['siteid']; 
if($siteid !=''){
  if(siteid =='1'){        
       echo json_encode(array('status' => 'not available'));
   }
   else{            
    echo json_encode(array('status' => 'available'));
   }        

}
else
{
     echo json_encode(array('status' => 'not a valid site id'));
}
```

**EDIT:**

This can be a content type issue also, use dataType as json, and you don't require to parse json explicitly, you can skip the line "jQuery.parseJSON(data);"

for your case its taking html I believe, its might add html/header tags so JSON.parse could not be parsed. see below, your modified code.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",               
    url: "checkSite.php",   
    data: { siteid : siteid }, //6 digit number
   dataType : 'json',
   accepts: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var objData= data;
        if(objData.status == "not available"){
            alert("Not Available");
            document.getElementById("add").disabled = false;
        }
        if(objData.status == "available"){
            alert("Available");
            document.getElementById("add").disabled = false;
        }
    },
    error: function(result){
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

Hope this will solve your problem!!